# Change button's background color via selector and manual performClick()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-styles

I have a button with the following background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/easy_button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
  <item android:state_focused="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/easy_button_pressed" /> <!-- focused -->
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/easy_button_default" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

This works great if I manually press the button. But I also at times need to manually call `button.performClick();` When I do this, the button does not change the color. Can someone please help me out.

Comment: Can we see your code Alex? More importantly, where/when are you calling performClick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After calling `performClick()`, call `view.setPressed(true);` and then set it to false after a few miliseconds like below:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        view.setPressed(false);
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: `view.setPressed(true);` is what I have been looking for. Thanks!